Why the state of a component is filled by deleted component?
I'm making a React project, and woundering why my component NoteComponent I don't delete changes every time. I'm new to React and don't understad how it works correctly.
If somebody can give piece of advice I will be so happy for your experience. Thank you.
I have the parent component "NotesWorkflow":
import React, { Component, ReactNode } from "react";
import { CurrentNote, Note } from "../../interfaces/Note.interface";
import { List } from "../../components/list/List";
import { ListProps } from "../../interfaces/list/ListProps.interface";
import { NoteComponents } from "../../services/createComponents";
import { DashboardState } from "../../interfaces/dashboard/DashboardState";
import { getAllMessages } from "../../services/requests";
import { NewNoteComponent } from "../../components/note/NewNoteComponent";

export class NotesWorkflow extends Component<
  {},
  CurrentNote &
    DashboardState & { notes: Note[] } & {
      NewNoteComponentBlockOpened: boolean;
    }
> {
  state = {
    notes: [],
    currentId: "",
    NewNoteComponentBlockOpened: false,
  };
  componentDidMount = async () => {
    this.setState({
      notes: await getAllMessages(),
    });
  };

  createNewComponent = async () => {
    this.setState({
      NewNoteComponentBlockOpened: true,
    });
  };

  render(): React.ReactNode {
    const { notes } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="dashboard__panel">
        <div className="dashboard__list">
          <input
            type="text"
            className="dashboard__search"
            placeholder="&#128269;"
          />
          <List
            notes={notes as ListProps[]}
            selectNote={(id) => {
              this.setState({ currentId: id });
            }}
            currentId={this.state.currentId}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="dashboard__notes__wrapper">
          <button
            className="note__button__addNew"
            onClick={this.createNewComponent}
          >
            Create a Note
          </button>
          {this.state.NewNoteComponentBlockOpened ? (
            <NewNoteComponent
              closeNote={() => {
                this.setState({ NewNoteComponentBlockOpened: false });
              }}
              addNewNoteDashboard={async (note) => {
                this.setState(({ notes }) => {
                  const oldNotesCopy = notes.slice();
                  oldNotesCopy.push(note);
                  return { notes: oldNotesCopy };
                });
              }}
            />
          ) : (
            ""
        )}
------------- HERE IS CREATING NOTES !!!!_!!!!_!!!!_!!!!
          {NoteComponents(notes, {
            selectNote: (id) => {
              this.setState({ currentId: id });
            },
            deleteNote: (id: string) => {
              const filtered = this.state.notes.filter((v: Note) => {
                console.log(`
                  ${v.id} =? ${id} =
                  ${v.id === id}`);
                return v.id !== id;
              });
              this.setState({
                notes: filtered,
                currentId: "",
              });
            },
            currentId: this.state.currentId,
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

The func "NoteComponents":
import { NoteComponent } from "../components/note/NoteComponent";
import { Note } from "../interfaces/Note.interface";
import { NoteProperties } from "../interfaces/noteComponent/NoteProperties.interface";

export const NoteComponents = (
  notes: Note[],
  noteProperties: Omit<NoteProperties, "note">
) => {
  return notes.map((v, i) => {
    return (
      <NoteComponent
        key={i}
        selectNote={noteProperties.selectNote}
        currentId={noteProperties.currentId}
        note={v}
        deleteNote={noteProperties.deleteNote}
      />
    );
  });
};

And the "NoteComponent":
import React, { Component, ReactDOM } from "react";
import { NoteProperties } from "../../interfaces/noteComponent/NoteProperties.interface";
import { Note, PrevState } from "../../interfaces/Note.interface";
import { patchNote, deleteCurrentNote } from "../../services/requests";

export class NoteComponent extends Component<
  NoteProperties,
  Omit<Note, "id"> & PrevState
> {
  mainRef: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement> = React.createRef<HTMLDivElement>();
  state: Readonly<Note & PrevState> = {
    ...this.props.note,
    prevState: this.props.note,
  };

  openNote = () => {
    const { id } = this.props.note;
    this.props.selectNote(id);
    this.mainRef.current?.classList.remove("closedClass");
  };

  closeNote = () => {
    this.props.selectNote("");
    this.mainRef.current?.classList.add("closedClass");
  };

  updateNote = async () => {
    const note: Note = {
      id: this.props.note.id,
      text: this.state.text,
      title: this.state.title,
    };

    const response: Note = await patchNote(note);

    const newState: Note & PrevState = {
      ...response,
      prevState: {
        ...response,
      },
    };

    this.setState(newState);
    this.closeNote();
  };

  deleteNote = async () => {
    const { id } = this.props.note;
    await deleteCurrentNote(id);
    this.props.deleteNote(id);
  };

  handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { currentTarget } = event;
    const name = currentTarget.getAttribute("name");
    if (name === "title") {
      this.setState({ title: currentTarget.value });
    } else {
      this.setState({ text: currentTarget.value });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { currentId, note } = this.props;
    const isOpened = currentId === note.id;
    const TextAreas = () => {
      if (!isOpened) {
        return (
          <>
            <h3>{this.state.prevState.title}</h3>
            <p>{this.state.prevState.text}</p>
          </>
        );
      }
      return (
        <>
          <textarea
            name="title"
            className="note__title"
            value={this.state.title}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <textarea
            name="text"
            className="note__text"
            value={this.state.text}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </>
      );
    };

    return (
      <div className={"note__wrapper " + (isOpened ? "openedClass" : "")}>
        <div
          className={"note " + (isOpened ? "" : "closedClass")}
          ref={this.mainRef}
          onClick={this.openNote}
        >
          <button className="note__close" onClick={this.closeNote}>
            x
          </button>
          <div className="note__content">{TextAreas()}</div>
          <div className="note__buttons">
            <button onClick={this.updateNote}>SAVE</button>
            <button onClick={this.deleteNote}>DELETE</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

When I delete the current note with deleteNote function, my note, that I don't delete, changes to the title and text deleted Note (but not an id)
Here is an example:
Created 3 notes
Delete note with title "2" and see the result
Deleted note with title "2" and note with "3" replaced to title "2"
After all we can see the changes and the 3 note not corresponding to its self, but id of the note is correct.
After reloading the page:
Note with title "3" is correct now
What could it be? Please, what I don't understand with setState?
I tried to request all notes in callback again and get all notes from scratch, but it doesn't give me the result I expect

The problem is in key attribute, every time I fill it with a new id, not the same. So I changed key from key={i} to key={note.id}. So I know that it's the same
